# Offer validity with date() function

Tags: php

I have created a function that will determine if an "offer" is currently valid. Each offer has a start and end date stored in a database and I use the date() function to figure if its valid. However, I have a problem since the following scenario is not returning "TRUE". I believe it should return "TRUE". What am I not getting?

```
$start = 2010-9-18  
$stop = 2010-10-10
// Current date is 2010-9-19

function is_active($start, $stop) {

$now = date("Y-n-d");

if($now >= $start && $now <= $stop) {
return true;
 }
}
?>
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You are missing quotes around your dates. But what's much more important: Do you need to validate dates beyond the span between January 1st, 1970 and 2038?

Comment: No, that won´t be necessary :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date()` returns a string. Strings are compared by lexicographical ordering. In this ordering, `9` is larger than `10` because `1<anything>` appears before `9<anything>`.

One simple fix is to use `Y-m-d` instead of `Y-n-d`, and record the `$start` as `'2010-09-18'`.

```
$start = '2010-09-18';
$stop  = '2010-10-10';
// Current date is 2010-9-19

function is_active($start, $stop) {

$now = date("Y-m-d");

if($now >= $start && $now <= $stop) {
return true;
 }
}
```